# Linux: Remember path to USB Device

Tags: linux

In Linux, Is there a way to remember/change a path to a USB device?

In my case, I need linux to remember that my USB serial adapter will stay on /dev/ttyUSB0, but when I unplug it and plug it back in, it switches to /dev/ttyUSB1.

I'm using a debian-based distro(mint), if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: [Custom `udev` rules](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+udev+naming+rules) can help here. I don't know how to write them, though.

Comment: btw, udev can't manage devices that were stopped improperly; if you just tear off usb flash drive, the /dev/sdb1 would live the whole way to reboot. (more a FS bug, but seen other cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get to know properties of the device while it is switched in:

   udevinfo -a -p $(udevinfo -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)

   If you have some newer distribution where udevinfo is not available, use this instead:

   udevadm info -q all -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)
2. Find some property that can identify the device (uniquely), for instance "serial"
3. Create a file called /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb-serial which contains the line:

   BUS=="usb", ATTR{serial}=="xxxx", NAME="ttyUSB0"

   Note the two equal signs for properties that are tested, and one for that which is assigned to.

Comment: Sweet, That did it! Thank  you kindly. 
I tested it with:
udevadm test  /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0/
and I saw the line:
node_symlink: creating symlink '/dev/customdevice' to 'ttyUSB0'

Success!