# Path to USB device changes spontaneously at runtime

Tags: hard-drive, usb, debian, raspberry-pi, jbod

I am running a *Raspberry Pi* with *Raspbian* (a Linux based on Debian Wheezy) as a *NAS* (Network Attached Storage) with an USB hard drive attached as **the only USB device**.

The issue I am confronted with is that the external USB hard drive is at `/dev/sda` but **changes at runtime of the operating system spontaneously** to `/dev/sdb` without any reason. Then while using it at `/dev/sdb` it jumps back to `/dev/sda`. It also happens while copying a big bunch of data resulting in I/O errors. Sometimes it takes hours but otherwise it takes minutes for this to happen. – This is really spooky!

Of course I considered the internet for clues before asking here for help. The only interesting thing I found was the following link: [Linux: Remember path to USB Device](https://superuser.com/questions/212443/linux-remember-path-to-usb-device) – I followed the described steps and I am posting here the output of the commands,

Command 1: `udevadm info -q all -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda)`

Output 1:

```
P: /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
N: sda
S: disk/by-id/usb-WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0
S: disk/by-path/platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=00JS-40NGB2
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=00JS-40NGB2\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=2336
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PATH=platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0_1_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=8DC88D250088
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=WDC_WD25
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=WDC\x20WD25
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=152d
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: UDEV_LOG=3
E: UDISKS_ATA_SMART_IS_AVAILABLE=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_COUNT=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=mbr
E: UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=7853442
```

Command 2: `udevadm info -q all -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)`

Output 2:

```
P: /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
N: sdb
S: disk/by-id/usb-WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0
S: disk/by-path/platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=00JS-40NGB2
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=00JS-40NGB2\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=2336
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PATH=platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0_1_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=8DC88D250088
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=WDC_WD25
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=WDC\x20WD25
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=152d
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=16
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: UDEV_LOG=3
E: UDISKS_ATA_SMART_IS_AVAILABLE=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_COUNT=1
E: UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=mbr
E: UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY=0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=2425648913
```

So I tried the trick and added the line `BUS=="usb", ATTR{serial}=="WDC_WD25_00JS-40NGB2_8DC88D250088-0:0", NAME="sda"` to the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb-serial` but unfortunately this also did not solve the issue.

I do not know if this is important to mention but the used external USB storage consists of two identical Hard drives of 256 GB of size in a [JBOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBOD#JBOD) controlled case. That means that it looks like one hard drive of 512 GB of size for the operating system.

And now I am looking forward to get any help and/or suggestions. – Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is _very_ weird. Where is your OS installed? The two outputs you show list different devices, are you _sure_ the `/dev` name of your disk is changing?

Comment: The OS is installed on a 4 GB SD card and the Raspberry Pi is booting from the SD card. But how do you see different devices in my output? Yes, I am very sure it is the same and only device attached to USB.

Comment: The `DEVPATH` and `P:` lines are different.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But it is the same USB device. I did not touch anything for these both outputs.

Comment: I know, it's got 2 disks though and that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had no further ideas to solve this issue I simply used another USB cable to attach the external hard drive to the Raspberry Pi and now it is working properly O_o It seems that the previous used USB cable was defective somehow.

Obviously the external hard drive previously lost connectivity to the Raspberry Pi for a short time. The operating system then was thinking that another hard drive was attached. Otherwise I cannot imagine that issue.

So this issue is officially solved now!

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's a USB attached drive, it switching between `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` on boot is not surprising; it doing it during normal sessions would lead one to suspect a screwy usb configuration on either the RasPi side OR the physical HDD itself (more the firmware that controls the 2 HDD's in the enclosure). That being said, check out this link on [UUID's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/), this pertains to Linux EXT3 partitions and judging from your output you have `dos` partitions (which is more likely FAT32 partitions) but you should be able to pull a UUID from the USB HDD using the `blkid` command as mentioned in [the article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/). [Here's](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1287333) [some](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1240146) links if you have trouble getting the UUID of your DOS partition.

IMHO if you're using the RasPi as a NAS and the USB drives are not going to be moved (i.e. the USB drive stays plugged into the RasPi 24/7), I'd recommend pulling the HDD's out of the USB enclosure and directly connecting them to the RasPi (if you can), this will avoid those I/O issues and give you higher throughput to your disks (SATA speeds vs. USB2 speeds).

Hope that can help out.